# How to declare date, time and datetime in java constructor and php mysqli ?

Tags: java, php, mysql

I've set column in mysql db with type String, int, double, float, date, time, datetime

If String, int, double, float data type can be declare as "sidf" in mysqli_stmt_bind_param , what about date, time, datetime?

And also in java , let say i create constructor name Req

```
Public class Req{
   Public Req(String name, int qty, double price, float pay, date? , time?, datetime?){}
}
```

What data type for those three (dare, time and datetime)?

Comment: There are `date`, `time` and `datetime` in SQL.

Comment: What i meant is in mysqli_stmt_bind_param , its gonna be on what kind ? Is it "sis" for date,time,datetime or something else ?  . Thanks btw for the prompt response. :)

Comment: Sorry, I understand now! I submitted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You insert it like any other string.

Although it's saved in the database as `Time`, `Date` or `DateTime`, it is still a string.

So you'd use `s`.

Example:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('insert into my_database (my_date) values (?)');

$my_date = '2016-10-06 12:00:00';
$stmt->bind_param('s', $my_date);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I see . I'll give it a try . Thank you for the answer .. Appreciate it :)

Comment: No worries! Hope this helps @Rozaimi

Answer (score 0):

you can use  java.util.Date, java.sql.Time and java.sql.Timestamp

```
Public class Req{
    Public Req(String name, int qty, double price, float pay, Date date,Time time,Timestamp datetime){
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try your answer .. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare date in mysql using the DATE keyword which has a format of 'yyyy-mm-dd'

About the time you can use the TIME keyword in mysql which has the format of 'HHH:MM:SS'

About the Datetime you can simply use the DATETIME keyword that has this format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'

So you could follow this syntax

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
col1 DATE,
col2 TIME,
col3 DATETIME);
```

and when dealing with it in java you can use

`java.sql.Date` for the DATE type

`java.sql.Time` for the TIME type

`java.sql.Timestamp` for the DATETIME